# Add privilege on Oracle ACL file without SYSDBA access

Tags: oracle, acl, sysdba

I´m trying to consume a Restful Service on Apex but I am getting the following error:

> Unauthorized URL

I managed to fix it before by creating an ACL file, adding the URL of the RESTful service and adding privileges to the `APEX_PUBLIC_USER`. But this time, I do not have access as a DBA and currently do not have communication with people who does, so I am trying to find a workaround on this, or finding another way to consume the web service without recieveing an error.

Do you know a way to consume a restful/web service without getting Unauthorized URL?

- Remember I do not have access to SYS since it is a shared DB and only have access to my container and the USER does not have SYSDBA
  privileges.
- The app is hosted in the cloud and we do not have access to the OS
  nor the DB, only to the SQL Workshop on apex using `APEX_PUBLIC_USER`
  account

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the people who do have DBA permissions and ask them. There are many ways for them to help you.

Or give us more information about what your exact issue really is.

The whole point of DB privileges is to prevent people from doing things they don't have access to.